# How can i display selected list element in update action?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

There are products in `Viewbag` which I display in dropdown list. It simply creates `MyModel` with selected product. But when I try to update `MyModel` and set `SelectedProduct` like this, dropdownlist is not showing selected one.

How can i display selected list element in update action?

```
public class MyViewModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public string SelectedProduct { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult CreateOrUpdate(int? id)
{
     var model = MyViewModel();

     if (id.HasValue && id.Value != default)
     {
          model = GetFromDatabase(id.Value);
     }
     else 
     {
          // This doesn't work
          model.SelectedProduct = model.Product;
     }

     ViewBag.Products = GetAllProductsFromDatabase()
                       .Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                       {
                            Text = x.FullName,
                            Value = x.Id.ToString()
                       }).ToList();;

     return View(model);
}

<div>
     <label asp-for="SelectedProduct"></label>
     <select asp-for="SelectedProduct" asp-items="@ViewBag.Products</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ActionResult CreateOrUpdate(int? id)
{
     var model = MyViewModel();

     if (id.HasValue && id.Value != default)
     {
          model = GetFromDatabase(id.Value);
     }

     ViewBag.Products = GetAllProductsFromDatabase()
                       .Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                       {
                            Text = x.FullName,
                            Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                            Selected=x.ProductId==model?.ProductId
                       }).ToList();

     return View(model);
}

<div>
     <label asp-for="ProductId"></label>
     <select asp-for="ProductId" asp-items="@ViewBag.Products</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Adding a little explanation about your code can help everyone understand what you did there. Better you explain, more it will help other people.